# How to parse multi dimentional json response in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

below is the json response which i'm getting,

```
{
    "day": ["Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
    "date": ["03-01-2012", "03-02-2012", "03-03-2012", "03-04-2012"]
}
```

i want to parse it for day and date differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The success function is something like this, yes?

```
success: function(data) { // data represents here the ajax json response
  var days = data.day;
  var dates = data.date;
  // Here loop through them, or do anything else you like
}
```

Basically you can treat JSON responses just like any Javascript object.